# Can't use `headers` or `dont_filter=True` while making inline requests in async method within scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I've created a script to scrape the `name`, `phone` and `email` address of different shops from yellowpages.com. I've used `async` method within scrapy to parse the email address from inner pages while parsing name and phone from the landing page. The script is doing fine.

What I can't understand is how I can use `headers` or `dont_filter=True` within the inline requests. The following is where I meant actually.

```
request = response.follow(email_url)
resp = await self.crawler.engine.download(request, self)
```

spider that I'm using:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class YellowpagesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "yellowpages"
    start_urls = ["https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Coffee+Shops&geo_location_terms=San+Francisco%2C+CA"]

    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36',
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        for start_url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(start_url,headers=self.headers)

    async def parse(self, response):
        for items in response.css("[class='result'] .v-card > .info"):
            name = items.css("a.business-name > span::text").get()
            phone = items.css("div.phones::text").get()
            email_url = items.css("a.business-name::attr(href)").get()

            request = response.follow(email_url)
            resp = await self.crawler.engine.download(request, self)
            email = resp.css("a.email-business[href^='mailto:']::attr(href)").get()
            yield {"Shop name": name, "Phone": phone, "Email": email}
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = CrawlerProcess()
    c.crawl(YellowpagesSpider)
    c.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it in `follow` itself. `follow` methods take all params that a `__init__` supports

```py
response.follow(email_url, dont_filter=True, headers=self.headers)
```

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.follow